# How to read a file located in in several folders and subfolders in Bash Shell

Tags: bash, scripting

There are several files named TESTFILE which  located in directories ~/main1/sub1, ~/main1/sub2, ~/main1/sub3, ..., ~/main2/sub1,~/main2/sub2, ... ~/mainX/subY where mainX is the main folder and subY are the subfolders inside the main folder. The TESTFILE file for each main folder-subfolder has the same pattern, but the data in each is unique.

---

Now here's what I want to do:

1. I want to read a specific number in the TESTFILE for each ~/mainX/subY.
2. I want to create a text file where every line has the following format [mainX][space][subY][space][value read from TESTFILE]

---

Some information about TESTFILE and the data I want to get:

1. It is an OSZICAR file from VASP, a DFT program
2. The number of lines in OSZICAR varies in different folder-subfolder combination
3. The information I want to get is always located in the last two lines of the file
4. The last two lines always look like this:

> DAV:   **2**     -0.942521930239E+01    0.27889E-09   -0.79991E-13   864   0.312E-06
>   **10** F= **-.94252193E+01** E0= **-.94252193E+01**  d E =**-.717252E-07**

Or in general, the last two lines pattern is:

> DAV: **a** b c d e f
>   **g** *F=* **h** *E0=* **i** *d E =* **j**

where the italicized parts are the parts that do not change and boldfaced variable are the ones that I want to get

---

Some information about main folder mainX and sub-folder subY:

1. The folders mainX and subY are all real numbers.

---

How I want the output to be:

Suppose mainX={0.12, 0.20, 0.34, 0.7} and subY={1.10, 2.30, 4.50, 1.00, 2.78}, and the last two lines of ~/0.12/1.10/OSZICAR is the example above, my output file should contain:

```
0.12 1.10 2 10 -.94252193E+01 -.94252193E+01 -.717252E-07    
...   
0.7 2.30 2 10 -.94252193E+01 -.94252193E+01 -.717252E-07
...
mainX mainY a g h i j
```

How do I do this in the simplest way possible? I'm reading grep, awk, sed and I'm very overwhelmed.

Comment: Both answers have indicated that further information is needed in order to fully answer your question. Please edit your question to provide details of the format of `TESTFILE`, indicating which part of it you would like to extract.

Comment: Thanks for adding to your question. Can you also add what you would like the output to look like?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the prompt reply. I edited the question and added some dividers to ease the reading of questions. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect the format of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using some `for` loops in bash:

```
for m in ~/main*/; do
    main=$(basename "$m")
    for s in "$m"sub*/; do
        sub=$(basename "$s")
        num=$(tail -n2 TESTFILE | awk -F'[ =]+' 'NR==1{s=$2;next}{print s,$1,$3,$5,$8}')
        echo "$main $sub $num"
    done
done > output_file
```

I have modified the command to extract the data from your file. It uses `tail` to read the last two lines of the file. The lines are passed to `awk`, where they are split into fields using any number of spaces and `=` signs together as the field separator. The second field from the first of the two lines is saved to the variable `s`. `next` skips to the next line, then the columns that you are interested in are printed.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I understood it except the awk part.  Also, will putting >output_file really put all the echoed information in a file. I tried it for my own for loop and no file is being created.  I also edited my question. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Does it work as expected? If so, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm really sorry for the late response. Thank you very much. I thought voting up an answer would be enough, but I wasn't able to do so because I lack reputation. The program worked with a bit of modification: for m in ./*/; do
    main=$(basename "$m")
    for s in "$m"*/; do
        sub=$(basename "$s")
        kpoints=$(tail -n2 ./$main/$sub/KPOINTS | awk NR==1'{print $1,$2,$3}')
 energy=$(tail -n2 ./$main/$sub/OSZICAR | awk -F'[ =]+' NR==1'{s=$2;next}{print s,$2,$4,$6,$9}')
        echo "$main $sub $kpoints $energy"
    done
done > OUTPUT

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear - specifically on how to extract the value from TESTFILE, but this is something like what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
for X in {1..100}; do
 for Y in {1..100}; do
   directory="main${X}/sub${Y}"
   echo Checking $directory
   if [ -f "${directory}/TESTFILE" ]; then
      something=$(grep something "${directory}/TESTFILE")
      echo main${X} sub${Y} $something
   fi
 done
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already made my question more specific. May I ask what -f means inside the if bracket, as well as the "Checking" part after echo? Thanks again.